# "via my application" isn't shown on most cell phones when my app posts to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, libcurl

We have an app on Facebook. It posts quotes hourly on behalf of users even when they are offline. But when php script runs to post to users timeline i am actually facing 2 serious problems.
Firstly and the most urgent is "via app name" is not shown under the username when you read news feed from new touch cell phones like BlackBerry, Samsung & iphone. This point is very critical since the app users don't like to post something on their behalf directly without "via app name".
Secondly the script is taking almost 40 secs to be excuted, however i have only 15 users till now. Please help. Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?PHP
require_once '../inc/config.php';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $db_name . ';host=' . $db_host . ';charset=utf8', $db_username, $db_password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sqlid  = "SELECT fb_id FROM offline_access_users";
$sqlmsg = "SELECT msg_id,message FROM fb_messages WHERE msg_id = (SELECT MAX(msg_id) FROM fb_messages WHERE sent = 'No' ORDER BY msg_id)";

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sqlid);

    $stmt->execute();

    $msg = $dbh->prepare($sqlmsg);

    $msg->execute();

    $msg_to = $msg->fetch();

    $msg_tosend = $msg_to['message'];

    $msg_tosendid = $msg_to['msg_id'];
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

while ($value = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $id  = $value['fb_id'];
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $id . "/feed";

    $ch = curl_init();

    $attachment = array(

        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'message' => $msg_tosend,
        'app_id' => $fb_app_id,
        'from' => $fb_app_id,
        'display' => "touch",
        'to' => "",
        'redirect_uri' => "http://mydomain.com",
        'link' => "",
        'picture' => "",
        'source' => "",
        'caption' => "",
        'description' => "",
        'actions' => ""
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$sqlupdate = "UPDATE fb_messages SET sent = 'Yes' WHERE msg_id=" . $msg_tosendid;

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sqlupdate);

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$db = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First problem "via App Name" is mostly not supported by the official Facebook App for Phones,Tablets . but you still see it from the `News Feed` from the Web Browser , it's a Facebook policy not your problem . like the official website for Twitter.

2- this is Optimization problem of your code and database query ! , since your using PHP , why you don't use the `Facebook PHP SDK` ?

**`PST`** : i know what you are really doing , you will face a lot of problems when you have a large number of subscribers , you have to optimize your publish algorithm , and **DON'T** Ever try to send the same post to all users at the same time , you application will be **banned** .

i made this script before and all those problems faced me , hope you bypass them .

Comment: Really thank you for your reply. I am still newbie to programming, therefore i am trying to get the best solution i found on internet. But at this point i have no clue and am stuck with. If you could give me a hand to figure it out, it will be highly appreciated.